# Trying to take a subset from an Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xls, xlrd

I am trying to write a simple program, just struggling to do it as I am learning Python.

I have an xlsx. It is of the format:

```
Team, Player
```

What I want to do is apply a filter to the field Team, then take a random subset of 10 players from EACH team.

I've started this out like so :

```
import xlrd

# First open the workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\1.xlsx')

# Then select the sheet. 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet_1')

# Then get values of each column. Excuse first item which is header so skip that
team = sheet.col_values(0)[1:]
players = sheet.col_values(1)[1:]
```

However I am kind of stuck with how to proceed here.

Can anyone offer any feedback/advice please ?

Comment: have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a dictionary keyed by the teams whose values are the list of players on those teams, and then sample from those lists:

```
import random

teams = {}
for t,p in zip(team,players):
    if t in teams:
        teams[t].append(p)
    else:
        teams[t] = [p]

samples = [random.sample(teams[t],10) for t in teams]
```

Comment: This is great, apologies for the time taken to reply - I was looking up and understanding the keyed dictionary. I get it now, it's kind of putting the data into buckets based on teams and printing from that. The last line is indexing into the teams list to take a random sample of 10 players, right? 

I changed the last line to print "team, player" like so -> samples = [teams[t] + random.sample(teams[t],1) for t in teams]

I believe this works! Thank you :D

Can you offer some help on how to deal in cases where the team has less than 10 players? At the moment it fails :)

Comment: @SimonKiely   `random.sample(teams[t],min(10,len(teams[t]))` won't throw an error. It will select all players when less than 10

Comment: Ah, thank you for this. I am running into some errors that are slightly different. I have posted a new question here with more details -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441499/trying-to-take-a-subset-from-an-excel/42441786#42441786 . Thank you for all your help, really useful and learned a lot from the use of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `filter` function -

```
filtered_teams = filter(lambda x: x[0] > 2, zip(team, players))
```

You can replace `lambda x: x[0] > 2` by you own filter, here its checking if any x[0] (or team value) is greater than 2 or not.

Now assuming players here itself is a list, you can iterate over `filtered_teams`

```
import random
print '\n'.join([random.sample(players, 10) for _, players in filtered_teams])
```

This is without using any external library, but you'll surely get better performance using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).